# How to create pretty URL's for category page queries in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I am trying to convert category links from queries to Pretty URL's.

For Example, I have category 'ALASKA'.
It's URL is `https://www.mywebsite.com/category/alaska/`

I am getting some queries from the url using following link:
`https://www.mywebsite.com/category/alaska/?subscriber=1`

I want to convert this URL to Pretty URL (`https://www.mywebsite.com/category/alaska/subscriber/`) and also want to display custom template for it.

I tried this code:

Try 1

```
function my_template() {
    if ( is_archive() ) {
        if ( isset( $_REQUEST['subscriber'] )  ) {
            $myurl = get_category_link();
            if (substr($myurl) != "/") $myurl .= "/";
            $myurl .= "subscriber/";
            $myurl .= trim( sanitize_title_for_query( $_REQUEST['subscriber'] ) ) . "/";
            exit( wp_redirect( $myurl ) ) ;
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_template_redirect' );
```

Above code didn't work for me.

I don't have enough knowledge about URL Rewriting in WordPress.

Please help me.

---

**UPDATE:**

Try 2:

As mentioned in [comment by Oussama](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49053030/how-to-create-pretty-urls-for-category-page-queries-in-wordpress#comment85111896_49053400)
I came up with this code:

```
function wallpaperinho_subcat_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^category/([^/]*)/subscriber/?','index.php?page_id=305965&subscriber=1','top');
}
add_action('init', 'wallpaperinho_subcat_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

The above function works, but I am not able to detect current category ID on the custom page and in the function. Is there any way to do it? So I can display different data with different categories.

Comment: Is a Pretty URL a URL which only has characters in `abcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz./:` ?

Comment: yes. I want to convert these query URL's to SEO Friendly URL's

Answer (score 0):

```
url = "https://www.mywebsite.com/category/alaska/?subscriber=1"
pretty = ""
for char in url: ## Loop through every letter in the 'ugly' URL
    if char in "abcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz./:": ## If the character is allowed
        pretty += char  ## Add it to the Pretty URL
```

EDIT: Just realised that your code is in PHP ... this code is in Python :( ... I'm working on a PHP version.

Comment: Thank You for the answer Adi C. May be someone else (Paython Coder) can find it useful. :) I will wait for your answer in PHP? :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about WordPress, what you are looking for is URL re-writing either with a `.htaccess` or `Apache` config.

Comment: Sorry but I am using NGINX as my server. And I want to know that how to do this in WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the link SEO friendly using .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$  category/$1/?subscriber=$2  [NC,L]
```

And then you can retrieve your var subscriber value using $_GET['subscriber']

Comment: I am using NGINX, But Thank You for your answer :) Is there any way to do the same in WordPress? Without using server side Rewrite Rules.

Comment: I think all you need is here:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/270397/seo-friendly-urls-for-my-plugin-categories#answer-270524
It explains step by step how to exactly do what you need